# GeoDistance calculation between two points using haversine formula

Tags: r

I write a function like this

```
    geodistance <- function (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{   
    lon2 <- lon2*pi/180;
    lat2 <- lat2*pi/180;
    lon1 <- lon1*pi/180;
    lat1 <- lat1*pi/180;

    dlon <- lon2 - lon1
    dlat<- lat2 - lat1
    a <- sin(dlat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)^2
    c <- 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
    d <- 3961 * c;
}   

    a<-geodistance(37.749421, -122.437600, 37.889378, -122.325592)
    a
```

Updated the post with the correct method and this time with correct parameters to find distance between 2 locations!

Comment: Your code is correct, `c` is not converted to integer, `geodistance(1, 2, 3, 4)` does not return 0. Maybe you have used a wrong formula in `a` or `c` or something else.

Comment: You may want to edit your post. It's rather normal that the geodistance between two **identical** points be zero ;)

Comment: Thanks :-)  ...never looked at the parameters !! it is working ..

Comment: since the answers were not useful for anyone (as it was oversight ), i updated the post to have a method to find distance between 2 positions in R.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question referring to a slight typo and not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, you appear to be trying to measure the distance between two points. In your example, the two points are the same point, so the distance between them is zero. Try different points and you get a different answer:

```
geodistance(37, -123, 38, -122)
# [1] 1.365098
```